# Getting pixel value of margin in ie7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

the problem is that if the margin is set to auto ie7 returns auto, while other browsers return the px value, for example look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pyadk/

In chrome it returns 0px, while ie7 returns auto

So, is there any way to force explorer to return the computed value of that margin?

Thank you

Comment: Force the user to download the Chrome rendering engine plugin for IE. That should do the trick :)

Comment: It would surely solve many of my problems, but sadly thats not how the world works :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a plugin calles JSizes that should solve your problem: http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/